# Sending a post request : same request, different behavior?

Tags: python, post

I am trying to remotely trigger actions on a website via post requests.

Here is an example of the request that is performed when I click the button on the website : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dd3sfzpc

And here is what I send : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eqsBDKUp.

I use the following code :

```
import time
import requests
import json
import urllib

session = requests.session()
login_data = {
    'Username': #the mail here,
    'Password': #the pass here,
    'submit': 'login',
}
res = session.post(#[the url where I log in], data=login_data)


rep=session.get(#[the url from which I get the session s data]).text

#below I fetch some data I need in the post request
p=rep.find('id="__EVENTVALIDATION"')
eventval=rep[rep.find('value="',p)+len('value="'):rep.find('" />',p)]
p=rep.find('id="__VIEWSTATE"')
viewstate=rep[rep.find('value="',p)+len('value="'):rep.find('" />',p)]
p=rep.find('id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"')
viewstategenerator=rep[rep.find('value="',p)+len('value="'):rep.find('" />',p)]

# parameters of the action
current_trade_currency="tx"
have="Robux" if current_trade_currency=="tx" else "Tickets"
want="Tickets" if current_trade_currency=="tx" else "Robux"
fromCur=10
toCur=100

tab={}
tab["__LASTFOCUS"]=""
tab["__EVENTTARGET"]="ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$SubmitTradeButton"
tab["__EVENTARGUMENT"]=""
tab["comments"]=""
tab["__VIEWSTATE"]=viewstate
tab["__EVENTVALIDATION"]=eventval
tab["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]=viewstategenerator
tab["rdoNotifications"]="on"
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$OrderType"]="LimitOrderRadioButton"
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$HaveAmountTextBoxRestyle"]=str(fromCur)
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$HaveCurrencyDropDownList"]=str(have)
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$WantAmountTextBox"]=str(toCur)
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$WantCurrencyDropDownList"]=str(want)
tab["ctl00$ctl00$cphRoblox$cphMyRobloxContent$ctl00$AllowSplitTradesCheckBox"]="on"

headers={
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Origin' : 'http://www.roblox.com',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.53 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Referer' : 'http://www.roblox.com/My/Money.aspx',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6'
}

session.post(#[the url where I perform the post request],data=tab).text.encode("utf-8"),headers=headers)
```

I cannot see any difference between the post request sent when the button is clicked, and the post request I send. However, my post request does not trigger anything.

What is the cause of this ?

Edit : here is a screenshot of some caracteristics of the request made by the website : [image]

Comment: Are you also sending the same cookies that the browser does?

Comment: @MarkR. The use of session() should handle that.. right ? Upon printing the cookies, most of them seem to be handled (except a few useless ones)

Comment: Try and pretend to be a browser by passing the User-Agent and Accept headers.

Comment: If a server decides to refuse fake request, you can do nothing even if you get everything right.

Comment: @MarkR. I have added "headers={
    'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11",
    'Accept' : 'text/plain'
}", but it didn't solve it.

Comment: @laike9m The thing is, other people have managed to do it (in Javascript) so I don't really know what's wrong with my python code.